# If i run a VPN service (paid) in the UK, do i by law have to keep logs?

Tags: privacy, security

So i want to start my own VPN company. Already have it setup and working etc but i'm based in United Kingdom (my servers are based in US though).

Because i am based in the UK, i know that law enforcement have supernatural powers over my service but by law do i need to keep logs? (For example: user login history and packet history)

Thanks for reading!